# Is it okay to replace a 127 V indicator LED with a 110 V one? (Both are AC)

Tags: safety, maximum-ratings

The available LEDs have no famous brand so they don't have a specific datasheet where you can search and look-up online. So I need a general answer to my question based on the "most common" behavior of the LEDs, or based on a previous experience that you may have had before.

I'm a sales electrical engineer and I want to sell the 110V LEDs to a factory and they will replace the existing 127V LEDs. I haven't tried it before but I would assume that the new 110V LEDs won't fail because the is no big difference in the rated voltage that they bear. I also think that the 110 V will be brighter, and their lifespan will be reduced a little.

Are my assumptions right and should I sell the LEDs based on these assumptions? Or Will they fail immediately (as if I connect a 12V LED to a 220V source)? Are there any factors to put into consideration?

Thank you so much,

[image]

Comment: A missing assumption: *A product with no data sheet is still produced to a high-quality standard*.

Comment: If you have no data sheet, did not test yourself, you have a liability issue in your hands if they don't work. There is a saying here along the lines of "no datasheet, no sale", meaning, people should not buy unknown components from unknown sources, and then make any assumptions about the advertized product. I suppose you have no safety and approval documents either, to prove they are tested and appoved for safety in your country? So it's really not about the lifespan, but guaranteeing operation and safety, if someone's life depends on those lamps. Or they start a fire because they are unsafe.

Comment: @Justme This is kind of a cheap product. Some customers don't want to pay much money to get it from trusted sources with approval docs and things like that. They just use what's written on the LED itself. Customer replace what they have with the exact ratings to guarantee that they work with the lowest cost possible. In my case, it's not the exact rating but close to. So I'm not really sure what to advice the customer.

Comment: @glen_geek What do you mean by a high-quality? Does this mean that they will bear the extra few volts?

Comment: @MichaelGeorge What voltage are they going to be used at? If it is 127 V then you may want to consider your reputation if they fail so often that it costs more to use the 110 V parts than to pay more for the correctly rated parts. Additionally, 127 V parts may have been specified so that they don't fail as often even if they are run on 110 V. Imagine that it costs $70 in someone having to do the job to get a lamp changed. "Pay cheap, pay twice."

Comment: `"most common" behavior of the LEDs` ... but you are not asking about LEDs ... you are asking about modules that contain a LED

Comment: If there is no datasheet, where did you find the rated voltage?

Comment: @Uwe written on the metal body of the led

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to ask your client why he had 127VAC LED modules before and what's the voltage of the wires leading to the indicator LED's in his installation. If your client answers that it's a machine working with a special power source giving 127VAC, then you should advise him to look for the same 127VAC LED modules. Because the 110VAC LEDs may shine too brightly and consume too much. They may fail earlier but this is still long/mid term issue. They won't fail after 3 weeks or something. But they will have to be replaced earlier.

Depending on the quality, and on the internal circuitry of the LED module, it could be that they perfectly support 127V without overconsuming and without yielding too much light and respecting their advertised lifespan. But since there is no datasheet and the product is classified as *cheap*, I wouldn't bet on it.

There is high chance that the voltage used is the regular 110VAC and that the old LED modules were rated with a margin *up to* 127VAC. But your client should confirm that this is the case. In this case, of course, there is no reason not to use them.

This more a commercial advise than a technical one: Always talk with the client and spend time explaining the pro and cons.